# How can I add a row with buttons to an excel table using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I'm using a form to add values to a table in excel:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()
    Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
    Dim newRow As Excel.ListRow
    Dim sheetName As String, tableName As String
    sheetName = "Dados"
    tableName = "articles"
    Set lo = getTable(sheetName, tableName)

    Dim ref As Integer
    ref = getMaxRef(tableName)

    Dim btnEdit As Button, btnDelete As Button
    'How can I add this 2 buttons to the newRow?

    Set newRow = lo.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
    newRow.Range = Array(ref, cboStores.Value, cboTypes.Value, cboMaterials.Value, txtDescription.Value, txtWeight.Value, txtPrice.Value)

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Is it possible to add the buttons directly in the newRow or do I have to search for the cells after adding the row and then add the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Here's general code. It aligns button's dimensions with dimensions of `A1` cell:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim btn As Button
    With Range("A1")
        Set btn = Sheet1.Buttons.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
    End With
End Sub
```